# How to calculate all records along with search from elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to execute search on a query (with certain requested records). How do I get count of total records in the same query itself.

```
    client = Elasticsearch(#conn_config)

    s = Search(index=index_name).using(client)
    outer_query = create_query(query_type='match', query=query)        
    s = s.query(outer_query)
    s = s[start_index:size]
    response = s.execute()


    def create_query(query_type,query): 
       return Q({es_query_type: {field_name: query}})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add `track_total_hits:true` (default is false) you will see the result in the search output.
In default, If you data size large than 10k you will see `hits.total.value: 10000`

```
GET /_search
{
  "track_total_hits": true
}
```

For python client you can check here: https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_dsl.html

[image]